# How to define macro with parameter in PHP as it is possible in C++?

Tags: php, c-preprocessor

Target is to have something like:

```
#define sum( f1, f2 ) ( f1 + f2 )
```

where

```
sum(2,2)
```

is 4 in PHP. Is that somehow possible? Even better would be if I could call:

```
$s = 'first';
APPEND ' and second';
```

when append will be defined as function/method/something else which is appending to `$s` so after those 2 lines `$s` would be 'first and second'.

Comment: I hope not. But then again, PHP has variable variables and added `goto` on demand... so I'm really afraid to find out. Also, what's wrong with `2+2` or `s .= ' and second';` (or, outside of such small examples, **functions**)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point of macros in C is that they are expanded at compile time.

Therefore, using the macros does not have an impact on the speed of your code, which a function doing the same would have.

Therefore, an example of usage is:

```
#define MYPRINTF(x) printf("MYPRINTF says : %s\n",x)
MYPRINTF("blah");
```

The code above will be translated by the compiler directly into:

```
printf("MYPRINTF says : %s\n","blah");
```

The whole point of it is that it is faster than defining a function, such as this one:

```
void myprintf(char *x)
{
  printf("myprintf says : %s\n","blah");
}
```

Because there is no overhead (in a function, you need to push arguments to the stack, etc).

In an interpreted language, like PHP, the above doesn't hold, as everything is executed directly during run-time, therefore using a mechanism like C's `#define` would be absolutely useless -- therefore, to answer your question, **simply use ordinary functions instead.**

Comment: This is not true, consider something like
    #define errorLog(message) error_log(__FILE__.':'.__LINE__.' '.message);
When you use a method __LINE__ would not display the correct line. (Just as an example)

Comment: This answer is not true and not covering the whole spectrum of a language. There is a situation where a `return` is useful in a `define`.

Answer (score 2):

just a thought from your comments

```
function withVeryLongWroteByAnIdiot() {
   ....
}

function xFunc() {
   return withVeryLongWroteByAnIdiot();
}
```

Comment: Better than that: `$short = 'functionWithVeryLongWroteByAnIdiot'; $short($a,$b);`

Comment: if it has really been written by an idiot, maybe you should seriously consider rewriting the function itself.. ;)
then you could choose any name you like..

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe PHP supports macros.  If you think about it, macros in C aren't fancy constants, rather constants are the world's most boring C macros.  PHP only understands the boring form through the [define function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php).

That said, I disagree with the other respondents about their validity. There is a valid reason for them: when you want to use built-in functions to preprocess something.  For example:

```
macro default_if_empty_value(value, default) (empty(value) ? default : value)
```

If you try to write that as a function and call it:

```
default_if_empty_value($this->that['something']->or[$other], 'Not here.');
```

then you'll get a PHP warning if any part of that variable chain is not defined, and the expanded version is harder to read:

```
empty($this->that['something']->or[$other]) ? 'Not here.' : $this->that['something']->or[$other];
```

PHP code *is* compiled, but it is compiled at runtime.  A macro like this would be expanded by the PHP interpreter and then compiled into PHP bytecode.  This bytecode is often cached by the PHP interpreter or an add-on like APC.

Answer (score 1):

PHP doesn't support macros in this sense, the (really quite valid) argument I believe being that there's not much difference between this and a normal function in PHP.

After all, it's not like there's any value in having a concept like this in a run-time interpreted language.

Comment: What if I have fuction with name functionWithVeryLongWroteByAnIdiot and I have to use it often? I would like to have macro so every time I write secondFunction(x) I really write functionWithVeryLongWroteByAnIdiot(x).

Comment: @Kuba: Languages that realized that reating functions as "first-class citizen" allow `f = functionWithVeryLongWroteByAnIdiot`. I bet PHP allows this too, although the syntax might be different (using references or something).

Comment: rewrite the function with a smaller name, maybe improve the function to justify the change as well

Comment: @Kuba - In C the macro is simply expanded out at compile time. As I've said (and you can perhaps imagine) this makes no sense in a run-time language.

Comment: I share the code and changing that name unfortunately isn't an option, I can make 'function shortName($x) { return functionWithVeryLongWroteByAnIdiot($x); } but I hope there is a better way to do this.

Comment: @Kuba: how would a macro handle that?  It's semantically the same as having a function shortcut...  I would suggest refactoring the code rather than trying to band-aid it with wrappers.  And write readable code more than easy to write code.  Who cares if the function name is long, if it is descriptive (there is a point where it's too long, but don't shorten just because it's easier to type)...

Comment: What if your macro did a bunch of code and included a return; at the end....a function isn't going to work in that case.